# Как залить background для половины блока?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

подскажите как можно залить только половину блока бэкраундом не используя background image

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Чем Вам не угодил `background-image` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div {
  height: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, green 50%, red 50%);
}
```

Цвета укажите ваши.

Comment: Все градиенты записываются так или иначе в `background-image`, при использовании `background`. И если у автора там уже стоит какая-то картинка, ваш градиент её затрёт.

Comment: @UModeL В вопросе никакой картинки в бэкграунде не было. )) Ну или пришлось бы рисовать псевдо-элемент before или after и рисовать бэкграунд уже к ним, но это детали.

Answer (score 3):

сделайте фон в виде градиента (сформировать градиент можно на онлайн сервисах, например https://cssgradient.io/)

```css
    .text {
        line-height:    50px;
        font-size:      36px;
        font-weight:    700;
        
        border:         1px solid black;
        background:     linear-gradient(0deg, red 0%, red 33%, rgba(0,166,255,1) 33%, rgba(0,163,255,1) 66%, white 66%, white 100%);
    }
```

```html
<div class = text>Мы рождены, чтоб сказку сделать былью</div>
```

Comment: Используя сводное свойство `background`, Вы всё равно скрыто используете `background-image`.